# Is it possible to return only the text of rule , using CodeEffects?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rules

I'm using CodeEffects https://codeeffects.com/Doc  for my rules and it's all good. But in a mvc view i want to show only the text from a specific rule that the user created, just as a summary view. Is there something in the codeeffects library that can help me with this please? To return pure text ?

Comment: Do you have a code sample that you've tried already to solve this problem? Posting it here may help everyone with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ToString()` on the rule editor object. It also has an override that takes a dictionary of GetDataSourceDelegates, if you use those.

Check out the docs here (there's no linking directly to the ToString-method, sorry): https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Editor-Net-Class